# building codedui project with VS2010 professional

Tags: coded-ui-tests, building

I have created my codedUI project using VS2010 Ultimate and build works fine when I am building from VS2010 Ultimate.

I am trying to build the same project using VS2010 Professional and when the build starts it complaints about missing assemblies one of the missing assemblies is "Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework"

**Is it possible to build CodedUI projects with VS2010 Professional?**

Answer (score 4):

The Visual Studio 2010 Professional version does not support the coded UI test, you might need to upgrade to the **Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate** or **Microsoft Visual Studio Premium**.

In new Versions of Visual Studio, Only **Visual Studio Enterprise** provide Coded UI Support and Visual Studio Professional & Visual Studio Community doesn't have support.

[image]
Please see for more details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380742.aspx

https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/compare/

Comment: Another place to view is http://www.visualstudio.com/products/compare-visual-studio-products-vs . Today this page show Visual Studio 2013, earlier versions for Visual Studio 2012 and Visual Studio 2010 were the same for Coded UI.